# Add an id to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to add an id to an element that I create dynamically using javascripts' *document.createElement()* method. Basically I want to create an iframe in my html document and at the same time give that newly created element an id.

Here's my code so far. I've figured out how to put the element in the DOM and all that, i just need the id.

```
function build(content){
      var newIframe = document.createElement("iframe");

      var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");

      newIframe.appendChild(newContent);

      var element = document.getElementById("container");
      document.body.insertBefore(newIframe, element);

      document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").id = "active";
    };
```

As you can probably see, I have tried to give it an id at the very end. Problem is, it doesn't work.

So if anyone has any idea of what is wrong here, or an alternative way of doing what I want to do, please feel free to express yourself. Many thanks!

Comment: simply: `newIframe.id= "active";` cause you already defined your element in `var` There's more, (and I don't understand why) you're trying to assing an `ID` actually to (plural) `ElementsByTagName` which is basically **incorrect** just cause `ID` **must** be unique. Like no-one is sharing your same insurance number :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add an attribute (`id` is an attribute) to that element [**directly**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id), like this:

```
var newIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
newIframe.id = 'active';
```

... although it looks quite strange to have id equal to `active` (too generic for a *unique* identifier).

Your current approach doesn't work because `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")` returns a collection of elements - `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` (it's [**browser-dependant**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)). While you can assign a value to its `id` property, it won't do what you mean to. To make it work, you can adjust it this way:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].id = "active";
```

... but, as shown above, there's a better way.

Comment: You might want to check that the `id` is not already in use, and increment a counter to find an unused one, e.g. `active3`

Comment: And that's exactly my point: what does `active3` mean? Is there a use case for more than one active element?

Answer (score 0):

```
newIFrame.setAttribute("id", "something");
```